# Comma separated list in Liquid

Tags: shopify, dotliquid

I am pulling metadata values in a for loop and need to display them in a comma separated list.

Code (whitespace added for readability):

```
{% if asset.metadata['field01'] %}{{asset.metadata['field01']}}{% endif %}
{% if asset.metadata['field02'] %}{{asset.metadata['field02']}}{% endif %}
{% if asset.metadata['field03'] %}{{asset.metadata['field03']}}{% endif %}
```

Currently this displays as: `Field 01 ValueField 02 ValueField 03 Value`, but I would like it to display as `Field 01 Value, Field 02 Value, Field 03 Value`

Manually typing `,` after each if statement leaves a comma after the last value.

Answer (score 8):

To print comma separated values from a list you could use the following:

```
{%for v in values %} {{v}}{% if forloop.last != true %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Like this comma is printed after all elements but the last one.

Answer (score 4):

You might find [my answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25783035/1367622) helpful.

1. Append each field to a string with a separator:

   ```
   {% assign metadata = "" %}
   {% if asset.metadata['field01'] %}
     {% capture metadata %}{{ metadata | append: asset.metadata['field01'] | append: "|" }}{% endcapture %}
   {% endif %}
   <!-- repeat for fields 2 & 3 -->
   ```
2. Use `split` and `join` to format the string for output:

   ```
   {{ metadata | split: "|" | join: ", " }}
   ```

This will ensure you don't get a trailing comma in your output.

Comment: Won't this do the wrong thing if the metadata itself contains `|`?

Answer (score 0):

Display comma separated shopify collection values.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
       {% for collection in product.collections %}
          <p class="collection-title">
             {{ collection.title }}
             {% if forloop.last != true %},{% endif %}
          </p>
       {% endfor %}
   </div>
```